# How to Create individual text files from a wmic output

Tags: windows, command-line, batch-file, wmic

I want to create individual text files from each entry in a wmic output.

So far I have

```bat
WMIC.exe /Node:localhost /Namespace:\\\root\SecurityCenter2 Path AntiVirusProduct Get displayName /Format:csv>AVlist.txt    
WMIC.exe /Node:localhost /Namespace:\\\root\SecurityCenter2 Path AntiSpywareProduct Get displayName /Format:csv>>AVlist.txt
```

that give me a list with the following

```
Node,displayName    
MAINCOMPUTER,Number1 Antivirus    
MAINCOMPUTER,Number2 Antivirus    
Node,displayName    
MAINCOMPUTER,Number2 Antivirus    
MAINCOMPUTER,Number1 Antispyware
```

What I want to do is create a series of text files that would be labled

```
Number1 Antivirus.txt    
Number2 Antivirus.txt    
Number1 Antispyware.txt
```

without having any duplicates, without overwriting any existing files and without saving the "Node,displayName" headers created each time wmic is run...

Now I've been struggling with this for a few days and have come up with a huge mess of a file that heavily relies on creating temp files and deleting them after... not elegant, overly complicated, I just hate it. So, I'm wondering if any wizards around here would have a simpler solution?

Here's the mess I've made so far. Don't look too closely at the shoddy coding.

```bat
WMIC.exe /Node:localhost /Namespace:\\\root\SecurityCenter2 Path AntiVirusProduct Get displayName /Format:csv>AVlist.txt    
WMIC.EXE /Node:localhost /Namespace:\\\root\SecurityCenter2 Path AntiSpywareProduct Get displayName /Format:csv>>AVlist.txt    
:: remove white spaces    
for /f "skip=1 delims=" %%a in (AVlist.txt) do (    
set str=%%a    
set str=%str:'=%    
set str=%str:,=%    
echo %str% >>%temp%\filetmp.txt    
)    
xcopy %temp%\filetmp.txt %~dp0\AVlist.txt /y    
del %temp%\filetmp.txt /f /q    
   
:: remove duplicate lines     
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion    
set inputfile=AVlist.txt    
set outputfile=AVlist2.txt    
   
echo File to be processed    
echo.    
type %inputfile%    
echo.     
    
if exist sorted.txt del sorted.txt    
sort %inputfile% /O %temp%\sorted.txt    
     
if exist %outputfile% del %outputfile%    
set lastline=     
for /f "delims==" %%L in (sorted.txt) do (    
set thisline=%%L    
if not "!thisline!"=="!lastline!" echo !thisline!>>%outputfile%    
set lastline=%%L     
)     
   
del sorted.txt    
     
echo Duplicates removed:     
echo.     
setlocal disabledelayedexpansion     
     
:: remove header     
ren AVlist2.txt AVlist2.txt.old     
findstr /v /b /c:"Node,displayName" AVlist2.txt.old > AVlist2.txt     
type avlist2.txt      
pause
```

Yikes!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand right what you try to accomplish, this batch will do:

```
@Echo off
For /f "skip=1 tokens=1,2 delims=," %%A in (
  'WMIC.exe /Namespace:\\root\SecurityCenter2 Path AntiVirusProduct Get displayName /Format:csv^|find "," '
) Do For /f "delims=" %%C in ("%%B") Do Find /I "%%A,%%C" "%%C.txt" >NUL 2>&1 ||(>> "%%C.txt" Echo:%%A,%%C)

For /f "skip=1 tokens=1,2 delims=," %%A in (
  'WMIC.exe /Namespace:\\root\SecurityCenter2 Path AntiSpywareProduct Get displayName /Format:csv^|find ","'
) Do For /f "delims=" %%C in ("%%B") Do Find /I "%%A,%%C" "%%C.txt" >NUL 2>&1 ||(>> "%%C.txt" Echo:%%A,%%C)
```

---

- There is no need for temporary files and sorting,
- directly parsing wmic output with a `for /f` and
- `skip=1` to get rid of the header,
- `tokens=1,2 delims=,"` to split the lines and store `node` to `%%A` and `displayname` to `%%B`
- `find` to check if the entry is already present in the destination file.

**EDIT3** Fixed batch, should work now.

Comment: Pretty close, and much cleaner than my previous mess... I did make the change for the namespace tag since I didn't realize the forum doesn't like double backslashes... But back to the code, I do still get the following error message "The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect."

Comment: Did an edit to the answer. To know what/where the error is run the batch with echo on and a pause at the end.

Comment: I just ran the code in a shell and it seems the problem is in the (>>"%%B.txt" Echo:%%A,%%B) part. I also fixed the namespace address so you'll be able to run it on your machine.

Comment: Problem is the damn wmic output in Unicode which is converted to current codepage but leaves `cr,cr,lf` sequences which have to be filtered out. On the way to change the above batch.

Comment: I too can't figure out why MS decided to do this... That's why in my script attempt I removed every space in the entries. It did help  a bit... I think.

Comment: It does work Flawless! Thanks! In the meantime, I managed to take a different route and make something that's a bit similar in result. But yours is cleaner than mine :-)

Answer (score 2):

Here's what I finally ended up making

Not as nice as the answer up above but it still works.

```
For /f "skip=2 tokens=1,2 delims=," %%A in (     
  'WMIC.exe /Node:localhost /Namespace:\\\root\SecurityCenter2 Path AntiVirusProduct Get displayName /Format:csv '
) Do (    
set str=%%a     
set str=%str:'=%    
set str=%str:,=%    
)|Find /i "%%A,%%B" "%%B.txt" >NUL 2>&1|(echo.>>"%%B.txt")
```

But since I like single line scripts, I'll be ditching this solution for the cleanest looking one